# Queues in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, data-structures, queue, kernel

I've been searching for information for a common kernel implementation of queues, that is, first-in-first-out data structures.  I thought there may be one since it's likely something that's common to use, and there's a standard for linked lists (in the form of the list_head structure).  Is there some standard queue implementation I can't find, or is it perhaps common practice to just use linked lists as queues and hope for the best?

Comment: what do you mean 'hope for the best'? what would you fear?

Comment: Eh, it's an expression.  I use it here since I seem to be using something in a way that isn't quite the norm.

Comment: Linked lists have operations which a FIFO queue does not (enumerate the list, remove items from the middle, etc). So personally, I'd fear that if a list is used as a queue without encapsulation, then in future some fool (probably me) will fail to observe the FIFO constraint.

Comment: A good reason for "hope for the best." :-P

Comment: quite true.  but i the few of those that i've checked in the Linux kernel aren't described as FIFOs, they're called lists.  i'd assume the code doesn't depend on strict FIFO behaviour

Comment: Well when you're dealing with a list that pushes from one end and pops from the other exclusively, it's generally good practice to impose such restrictions, to avoid the kind of confusion described above.  At least that's what I've been taught.

Comment: Although I agree with that in principle, and argued for it above, I will note that linux kernel code is generally written on the assumption that everyone involved knows exactly what they're doing. So it's probably rarer to make explicit abstractions than would be general good practice.

Comment: In other words, yes, they're "hoping for the best". But it's a reasonable hope - anyone coding at a low level must be dealing carefully with unencapsulated pointers and structures all the time, so one would hope they can be trusted with a list. I just wouldn't recommend it in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, the Linux kernel typically uses linked lists to implement queues.  This makes sense, because linked lists offer the required behavior.  See this example from kernel/workqueue.c:

```
  INIT_LIST_HEAD(&wq->list);
  // ...
   case CPU_UP_CANCELED:
            list_for_each_entry(wq, &workqueues, list) {
                    if (!per_cpu_ptr(wq->cpu_wq, hotcpu)->thread)
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for include/linux/kfifo.h?
From the heading:

> A simple kernel FIFO implementation.

It's rather new anyway, so it's not hard to find direct usages of linked lists. Also, they have a quite different implementation (FIFOs are implemented as circular buffers), so they have different applications.

Note also they are designed with multithreaded usage in mind (think to producer/consumer queues), but you can use them without locking with __kfifo_put/__kfifo_get.

Btw: I remember I learned about them on lwn.net - bookmark this: lwn.net/Kernel/Index, and read the entry about kfifo :-).

From your ex-kernel developer,
Blaisorblade

Answer (score 4):

You seem to confusing an abstraction (a fifo queue) with an implementation (a linked list).
They are not mutually exclusive -  in fact queues are most commonly implemented as linked lists - there is no "hoping for the best".