# Linux kernel datastructures

Tags: linux, data-structures, kernel

I am new to module writing and need a circular buffer[1] and a vector. Since the Linux kernel apparently provides some data structures ([lib](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/lib)) (list, trees), I was wondering if there is a **vector equivalent**?

While I think I am well capable to write my own, I prefer libraries for such things to prevent the duplication of code and to avoid errors.

[1] Found while composing the question, [kfifo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/kfifo.h), also [Queues in the Linux Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/389582/258418) might be of interest.

Comment: are you speaking about a C++ vector ? Are you only considering C ?

Comment: @user2485710 since I was advised to write modules in C I am only considering C. And yes I do have a stronger C++ background than C and I am thinking of 'the' c equivalent to a C++ `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no implementation of vectors till 4.1 Linux kernel. And it does not make any sense to have one as vectors can be designed with the basic data structures whose implementation is already provided in Linux kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, meanwhile I changed my algorithm slightly to use lists. Your answer would be more helpful (and get accepted) if you suggest the basic data structure of choice to implement a vector (while a list could work it has more overhead/pointerchasing), so what do you recommend and why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but if anyone needs to implement a generalized vector in C, it can be done using void pointers and a `sizeof` operator on initialization. It would look something like this:

```
struct MyVec {
  void *data;
  size_t stored_sizeof;
  size_t size;
  size_t allocated_size
};

#define STARTING_ALLOCATED_SIZE 10

void MyVec_init(struct MyVec *self, size_t sizeof_data_type) {
  self->stored_sizeof = sizeof_data_type;
  self->data = malloc(self->stored_sizeof * STARTING_ALLOCATED_SIZE);
  self->size = 0;
  self->allocated_size = STARTING_ALLOCATED_SIZE;
}

void MyVec_deinit(struct MyVec *self) {
  free(self->data);
}

bool MyVec_at(struct MyVec *self, size_t index, void *to_fill) {
  if (index >= size)
    return false;

  memcpy(to_fill, self->data + (index * self->stored_sizeof), self->stored_sizeof);
  return true;
}
```

and all the other methods that you might need, just being sure to use `stored_sizeof` whenever indexing, adding/removing elements, and the like.